# Kibana does not show data from frozen indexes in search/Discover of ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

When I search a time-period last august where I only have frozen index-data, kibana finds no matches. 
When I unfreeze one of the-augest-indexes Kibana Discover finds the data. If I freeze it again, no data again.
I'm using ELKStack 7.5.2.

What gives?

According to [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/frozen-indices.html) they should be searchable. I'm pretty sure no other queries are running, so it cannot be the frozen-search limit by search_throttled (well unless its zero or some weird thing).

Comment: Do you have access to the elasticsearch logs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for

search:includeFrozen

Includes frozen indices in results. Searching through frozen indices might increase the search time. This setting is off by default. Users must opt-in to include frozen indices.

This needs to be set under advanced settings in Kibana.

Official link: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I see, its a global-setting I can enable/disable when the need to search frozen data arises. I noticed I had to refresh the second browser window with my discover after changing setting in the first window.